# How to get all files from a directory and display them on a list in tkinter - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is a bit hard to explain but imma do my best.

Imagine a have a dir ( `~/.profiles` )
In this dir there are two files ( `fileone.msp` and `filetwo.msp` )
I assign these files to a variable with

`from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]`

Now I want to have a button for each of these files with the name of the file found.
So lets say the output is `files = ["fileone.msp", "filetwo.msp"]` , now I want a tkinter window with two button with one saying fileone.msp and another saying filetwo.msp.
In case it was three files ( third being called `filethree.msp` ) I wanted three buttons each one with names and so on and so forth.

Thanks! I hope I explained my self.

Comment: You should start by working through a basic tkinter tutorial.

Comment: Hey Bryan! This isnt my first time using tkinter, nor my second, nor my third :p

Comment: I have made tkinter programs some times before, its just that I can't do this specific thing.

Comment: So, what about this problem are you struggling with? All you're asking is how to display two buttons (or a listbox -- your title and body seem to ask two different questions), it doesn't get much simpler than that.

Comment: I will reform my question :(

Comment: Question reformed buddy

Comment: I still don't see the problem. I assume you know how to iterate over a list in python. So, iterate over the list, creating a button for each. What part of that are you struggling with?

Comment: Im struggling with, *gets sad for being a noob* not knowing how to interate? If you could answer me how to do it I would appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly (and I doubt that I do...), to create buttons from a list you simply iterate over the list like you would for any other task:

```
for file in files:
    button = tk.Button(root, text=file, ...)
    button.pack(...)
```

Comment: Ill test this later. Can you suggest something for me to improve my question?

Comment: @HiperBolt: the best suggestion I can give is to try to solve the problem on your own with the smallest amount of code possible, and then ask a specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: Makes sense, well now that I have got a base to start with, I think I can start doing that. Either way I cant ask questions for 2 days..

Comment: It works! Who would have guessed it was this easy! Thanks, a lot! :)

Comment: Help me out here, it generates the buttons properly, but whenever i assign a command to it ( lets say its command=lambda: print(file) ) it just prints the last button it made

Comment: @HiperBolt: search this site. That problem has been asked about and answered many times.